# search and replace specific positions of a fixed-length file

Tags: shell

I have several fixed length files where every position or position range is reserved for a particular field. The first few fields are year, term, name, DOB, gender...

Year starts in position 1 and is of length 2

Term starts in position 3 and is of length 1

Name starts in position 4 and is of length 35

DOB  starts in position 39 and is of length 6

Gender starts in position 45 and is of length 1
...

This is true for all files. Not all fields are always present. Example, Name field may be 35 blanks/white spaces since it was not reported. The same may be true about other fields.

I need to search the Name field (whether it has a value or not and replace its contents with a dummy string which could be 'xxxxxxxx' but the length should not exceed 35 and after string replacement the position of all fields should not have changed.
All files have 80 fields.

Sample file containing 3 lines. Each line begins with 182:

182                                         1                                                                                              405080711    001       0425594
07   5                        4170000000000000         00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000
9      05000002

182                                         1                                                                                              205080712    001       0480201
07   5                        3300000000000000         00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000
05000004

182                                         2                                                                                              005080713    001       0425824
07   5                        3080000000000000         00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000        0000
05000005

'''
I am using the following sed command to replace a blank Name field with the below string.
However this overwrite all fields prior to Name which starts at position 35

sed -E 's/^(.{3})(.{36})/First Name of the student-Last Name/' File_name
'''

Open to use any other command such as awk etc.
Actual white spaces between fields may not be showing here due to auto formatting.
In sample line 1 above there are actually 41 spaces between "182" and "1"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4L5A.png)
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl`:

```sh
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $name = sprintf "% -35.35s", "xxxxxxxx" }
          substr($_, 3, 35) = $name' input.txt
```

`perl` uses 0-based indexes, so this replaces the 35 characters of each line of the input file starting at the 4th character with the value `xxxxxxxx` padded with enough trailing spaces to make 35 characters total (And if `xxxxxxxx` is more than 35 characters long, truncates it to 35). The modified line is then printed to standard output. Use `perl -i -pe '...' input.txt` to modify the file in place.

---

Or a similar `awk` version:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { name = sprintf "% -35.35s", "xxxxxxxx" }
     { printf "%s%s%s\n", substr($0, 1, 3), name, substr($0, 39) }' input.txt
```

`awk`'s `substr` doesn't have a way to replace part of a string like `perl`'s does, so this one extracts the parts before and after the name field and prints them all out with the new name value. Not as elegant but gets the job done.

Comment: I tried the Perl version and It worked great! Thank you very much. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: A follow up to this older question.
Could you please explain the significance of "-35.35".
I understand 35 is the length of the string to be replaced.
More specifically the decimal points ".35"? 
Thanks, appreciated.